# Error every time running H2OXGBoostEstimator

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, h2o, xgboost

I randomly encounter the same error whenever I run XGBoost model (both the normal run and grid search). The error message says this:

`H2OConnectionError: Local server has died unexpectedly. RIP.`

I don't know what happens, I tried to change versions but didn't work. I'm currently using the version 3.18.0.5. Does anyone have any idea what is happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the logs.

Comment: Unfortunately no logs printed

Comment: This is how to download logs: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/logs.html  If you can edit your post to include the end of the log where the failure occurs, that would be helpful.

Comment: Did you somehow manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen this happen is when H2O runs out of memory.  Please check that you have enough memory -- an H2O cluster should have at least 4x the amount of RAM as the dataset you're trying to train a model on (data size on disk).

Comment: @KingJulien Why are you commenting here for another issue?  Your comment is not related to this question or my answer.